# Multiple JUnit tests using FEST

Tags: java, swing, junit, junit4, fest

I've written several JUnit test methods to test my Java Swing GUI (using [FEST](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki)). My class is in the following format:

```
public class Tests
{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception { ... }

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception { ... }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception { ... }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception { ... }

    @Test
    public void testA() { ... }

    @Test
    public void testB() { ... }

    @Test
    public void testC() { ... }

}
```

When I run this class in Eclipse, it only runs the testA test, and not testB or testC. If I comment out testA, testB runs - so it seems to just run the first test each time.

JUnit in Eclipse shows 'Runs: 2/3' after it has completed the first test, but doesn't progress any further, or show any errors.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm using JUnit 4.8.1 and FEST 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have a side effect in `testA` that is blocking the code in `testB` from running. It's hard to say what is happening without the details in `testA` and `testB`, but I can give you some general guidance.

You are off to a good start by commenting out `testA`. When you do this, do both `testB` and `testC` run?

Try drilling down into `testA` and slowly commenting out the details in what's underneath `testA` until you tests run both `testA` and `testB`. Once you've done this, you at least know **where** the problem is.

For example, if you code looks something like:

```
public void testA() {
    doX();
    doY();
    doZ();
    // Assert stuff
    ...
 }
```

comment out everything after `doX()` and see what happens. If that works, then uncomment `doY()` and see what happens. If it didn't work, then drill down into `doX()` and start commenting out and re-running your tests again.

This should help you to pinpoint the details of where things are going wrong. If you are still stumped when you figure this out, come back and ask a question around those details.

Good luck finding your bug!

Comment: Thanks for your help. After commenting out all the other methods and finding it still just ran the first one each time, I had a look at the beforeClass() and before() methods. It seems it was a problem with how I'm using FEST.

I had window = new FrameFixture(frame) in the before() method, instead of the beforeClass() method. After changing this, it seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code snippet is OK.

You may check if each @Test method is **independent** to others, each test method shouldn't share same context. Ensure `@Before` and `@After` have correct behaviors.